# Windows API tag cleanup

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32) refers to the current incarnation of the Windows API, regardless of whether it's being used in a 32-bit or 64-bit application.  We also have [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) and [win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32api) to refer to this API.  (We don't have tags for Win16 or Win32s, which were monikers used to clarify the particular flavor of the API during the 16- to 32-bit transition era.)

Meanwhile, we have a [win64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win64) tag, whose description says it's about 64-bit versions of Windows (the operating system), yet some extrapolate from Win16 and Win32 and conclude that win64 must refer to a Win64 API, which isn't a thing.  (Though I did find [this Microsoft article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496995.aspx) that does uses "Win32" and "Win64" to refer to two distinct versions of the API int he way that "Win16" and "Win32" used to be used.  Note that only Win32 is claimed as a trademark.)

While it seems we've coped just fine for a long time with three tags for the current Windows API, the win64 tag causes confusion.

Should we nix the [win64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win64) tag or merge it into [windows64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows64)?

Comment: It just has a bad description, it needs to be edited so it is crystal that it describes the 64-bit version of the winapi and not the OS.  All top answerers know what it means so it hasn't caused a lot of confusion yet.  Joel Spolsky didn't know what it means :)   Let me know if you want me to edit it.

Answer (score 5):

The [win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32) tag doesn't actually exist. It is a synonym of the master tag, [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi). You could make a technical argument that this is incorrect, since the API is actually the *Win32 API*, but I think clarity wins out over perfect technical accuracy here. As you point out, the name Win32 is confusing to many who don't know that it simply means the "standard" Windows API (now that 16-bit Windows is long dead and buried).

Similarly, since there is no "Win64" API, I think it would make sense to merge the [win64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win64) tag into the same master [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag and make it a synonym. Then, it would behave exactly like [win32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win32). There's no need to have a unique tag for something that doesn't exist. That just breeds confusion and promotes mistagging. I watch questions with the [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) tag, but I don't watch questions with the [win64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win64) tag, mostly because I didn't know about it until today. I suspect other top answerers for this API are in a similar situation. The purpose of tags is to maximize the chances that experts will see your question.

If you want to talk specifically about 64-bit issues, then use the [64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/64bit) tag (of which, [x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/x64) is also a synonym). That tag can be combined with [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/winapi) if need be.

Similarly, a [windows64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows64) tag shouldn't exist, either. This should either be manually removed, or merged and synonymized with the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag. Few to none of the questions I see with this tag actually refer to the Win32 API used from a 64-bit application. They're just about incidental programming on Windows, where the person happens to be running a 64-bit version. Again, if need be, the [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) tag can be combined with the [64bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/64bit) tag when one needs to indicate something unique to the 64-bit world.